# bootstrap.yml and AWS user data

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, config, user-data

I have Spring Boot based application deployed to AWS EC2 instances. The application is a Spring Cloud Config Client.

I would like to configure the URL to my Spring Cloud Config Server via AWS user data (using Spring Cloud AWS).

I can already access the user data via @Value annotations. However if I try to refer to user data inside bootstrap.yml, it's not able to resolve it.

```
spring:
application:
    name: network-device-service
cloud:
    config:
        uri: ${SPRING_CONFIG_URI}
```

Any ideas if this it at all possible in bootstrap.yml?

Comment: Where are you declaring "${SPRING_CONFIG_URI}" ?

Comment: In AWS user data.

Comment: Did you manage a way to fix this? I have the same issue.